# "Flag as Duplicate" suggesting another duplicate

Tags: discussion, bug, flags, duplicate-questions

Today, I was looking through StackOverflow and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559895/save-arraylist-in-txt-file). It is a very simple question, and I know I've seen it answered before, one way another, so I went ahead and clicked on Flag -> Duplicate. What came up was pretty interesting:

[image: Duplicate Selection in list]

One of the items in the list was itself a duplicate!

[image: Duplicate Selected]

I think this may be a bug - the possible duplicate list should NOT offer a question already marked as a duplicate like that. It should instead offer the most original question, not marked a duplicate. Changes of "Duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate" aren't very helpful.

Comment: related: [Duplicates of duplicates should be remapped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199788/165773) at MSE and [Multiple indirection in closed duplicates and transitivity of duplicates](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5896/31260) at Programmers meta

Comment: Sometimes a duplicate is a better duplicate than the last leg of the chain.  They shouldn't be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding duplicates from the results completely would make it much more difficult to track down original questions, as those are not necessarily worded in the same way as the duplicates.

The similarity search is implemented using the same elastic search index we have for the search box, which unfortunately doesn't contain data about the original posts of a duplicate, so adding this would be quite expensive (basically making this more of a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)...). Also, we can't reasonably go through all the returned posts and resolve the duplicates for each post in the set, in order to remove the duplicate's who's parents are already in the list. Additionally, the duplicates and their originals can create complex relationship graphs with loops etc., which causes all sorts of fun.

My proposal would be to just forward you to the original question when you click on the link in the duplicate notice.

Comment: That is what I meant by proposal - not to hide the duplicates, but to replace them with what the question is a duplicate of!

Comment: What I'm saying is, replacing is tricky, I'd just make it easier to navigate around/to the original

Comment: I thought ceation of loops would be rejected by the software...?